# Rails routing with namespaces and nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I have an `email_template` model that has a nested resource `moves` to handle moving an `email_template` from one folder to another.

However, I want to namespace these actions in a `:templates` namespace because I have several other resources that are template items as well.

Since I'm namespacing, I don't want to see `templates/email_templates/:id` in the URL, I'd prefer to see `templates/emails/:id`.

In order to accomplish that I have the following:

```
# routes.rb
namespace :templates do
  resources :emails do
    scope module: :emails do
      resources :moves, only: [:new, :create]
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works fine when I do CRUD actions on the emails, since they are just using the `:id` parameter. However, when I use the nested `moves`, the parent ID for the emails keeps coming across as `:email_id` and not `:email_template_id`.  I'm sure this is the expected behavior from Rails, but I'm trying to figure out how the parent ID is determined.  Does it come from the singular of the resource name in the routes, or is it being built from the model somehow?

I guess it's ok to use `templates/emails/:email_id/moves/new`, but in a perfect world I'd prefer `templates/emails/:email_template_id/moves/new` just so developers are clear that it's an `email_template` resource, not a `email`.

```
# app/controllers/templates/emails_controller.rb
module Templates
  class EmailsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @email_template = EmailTemplate.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/templates/emails/moves_controller.rb
module Templates
  module Emails
    class MovesController < ApplicationController
      def new
        # Would prefer to reference via :email_template_id parameter
        @email_template = EmailTemplate.find(params[:email_id])
      end

      def create
        @email_template = EmailTemplate.find(params[:email_id])

        # Not using strong_params here to demo code
        if @email_template.update_attribute(:email_tempate_folder_id, params[:email_template][:email_template_folder_id])
          redirect_to some_path
        else
          # errors...
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could customize the parameter as:

```
resources :emails, param: :email_template_id do
      ...
end
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error "missing required keys: [:email_id]" and when I look at the params hash: `{"param"=>:email_template_id,
 "controller"=>"templates/emails/moves",
 "action"=>"new",
 "email_id"=>"1"}`